# Downloaded images displaying as oversize

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, ios-autolayout

In my project all images downloaded from URL display as oversizes. Now I using Kingfisher but if to use default function will be same.

[image: Photo]

But proportions should view as below:

[image: Photo]

If turn off the option of display from URL and to use default image from library that proportions will be properly. Then I did conclusion that my problem not in constraints and layout but in the code. Maybe I wrong.

[image: Photo]

In addition image downloaded from URL displays not right away or after the download. They display after long tap.

[image: Photo]

Where did I a mistakes in my project? Why I receive oversized image and they not display right away or with delay for download but after long tap?

**Code of the ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var n = 1
var title_segue = ""
var id_segue = ""
var categories_segue = ""
var tags_segue = ""
//var refresh: UIRefreshControl!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoNewsCell
    //print("cell: "+(self.videonews?[indexPath.item].headline)!)
    //cell.imageView!.downloadImage(from: (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)!)
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)!)!, cacheKey: self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)
    cell.imageView!.kf.setImage(with: resource)
    cell.titleVideo.text = self.videonews?[indexPath.item].headline
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Launch tableview in SecondView")
    title_segue = (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].headline)!
    id_segue = (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].id)!
    categories_segue = (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].categories)!
    tags_segue = (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].tag)!
    //print(("tableView: "+(self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!))
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "video2newsbody", sender: self)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.videonews!.count
}

@IBOutlet weak var videoTableview: UITableView!
var videonews: [VideoNews]? = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJSON()
}

@objc func getJSON(){

    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://sportarena.com/wp-api/wp/v2/posts/?per_page=13&page=\(n)&tags=22&_embed")!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        self.videonews = [VideoNews]()
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSArray

            for arrayX in json as! [[String: Any]] {
                let VN = VideoNews()

                var image_url = "https://sportarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Grey_full.png"

                let tag0 = arrayX["tags"] as? NSArray

                let categories0 = arrayX["categories"] as? NSArray
                let title0 = arrayX["title"] as? [String: Any]
                let embedded = arrayX["_embedded"] as? [String: Any]
                let featuredmedia0 = embedded?["wp:featuredmedia"] as? NSArray
                let featuredmedia = featuredmedia0?[0] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let media_details = featuredmedia?["media_details"]
                let sizes0 = media_details?["sizes"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                let sizes = sizes0?["video-small"]
                if (featuredmedia0 != nil || featuredmedia != nil || media_details != nil || sizes0 != nil || sizes != nil) {
                    image_url = sizes?["source_url"] as! String
                }

                if let ID = arrayX["id"],
                    let date = arrayX["date"],
                    let title = title0!["rendered"] as? String,
                    let categories = categories0?[0],
                    let tags = tag0?[0] {
                    VN.headline = Html().convert(from: title)
                    VN.image = image_url
                    VN.id = "\(ID)"
                    VN.date = date as? String
                    VN.categories = "\(categories)"
                    VN.tag = "\(tags)"
                }
                self.videonews?.append(VN)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.videoTableview.reloadData()
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "video2newsbody") {
        let NewsBodyController = segue.destination as! NewsBody
        NewsBodyController.title_news = title_segue
        NewsBodyController.id_news = id_segue
        NewsBodyController.categories_news = categories_segue
        NewsBodyController.tags_news = tags_segue
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it something to do with the drawing cycle, make sure that the content of the image view are clipping to the bounds of the draw rect:
[image]
Then you can also specify how to draw the content with contentMode property, because the default is to scale the content to fit the size of itself by changing the aspect ratio of the content if necessary. More on : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/contentmode

In addition to display( or draw) that images obtained from Kingfisher you need to tell the system to do so, one option is to set the imagesfrom imageView to nil when dequeuing a cell and then set the new image, this will call the drawing system.

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell....
//print("cell: "+(self.videonews?[indexPath.item].headline)!)
//cell.imageView!.downloadImage(from: (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)!)

   cell.imageView.image = nil //option 1

let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: (self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)!)!, cacheKey: self.videonews?[indexPath.item].image!)
cell.imageView!.kf.setImage(with: resource)
cell.titleVideo.text = self.videonews?[indexPath.item].headline

    // option 2 : cell.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()

return cell
```

Comment: Unfortunately all three options not fixed the problem. Maybe is there more options?